# How to fix script where jQuery hide function is being ignored/not executed for a specific id

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to hide a link on my webpage using the jQuery hide function. I have the function in an inline script and for some reason, this link will not be hidden.

I have the hide function nested in a jQuery(document).ready function and have tried it outside this ready function and neither work. I can input the hide function into the console in the browser (using Chrome) and it removes the link I want removed perfectly. I also have a few other things being hidden in this script, specifically some text areas, and they are being hidden correctly, so the script is executing.

```html
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.HiddenContent').hide();
jQuery('#picker-link').hide();});
</script>
```

```html
<textarea class="HiddenContent">example</textarea>
<a id="picker-link">link text</a>
```

This should hide the link based on that it works for the textarea, and I cannot figure out why it is not. I'm not seeing any error message as this function works if input into the console directly. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should wait until the `DOM` is ready before hiding.
Try to put your `.hide()` inside a `$( document ).ready(function() { $('#picker-link').hide(); });`

Answer (score 1):

So I tried the following and it worked. The thing with jquery is you have to wait until the document is ready and then it will work. Also make sure you specify which library you are using with jquery. For example, I use googleapis.com.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.HiddenContent').hide();
        $('#picker-link').hide(); 
       });
     </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <textarea class="HiddenContent">example</textarea>
      <a id="picker-link">link text</a>
    </body>
</html>
```